# Как правильно сверстать такого вида блок?

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, flexbox

Практикую верстку, не могу сообразить как правильно организовать такого вида блок:
[image: макет]
Из макета можно увидеть, что background у блоков разный и занимает 100% ширины всего экрана, при это имеется контент, который находится в контейнере определенной ширины (1150px). Уткнулся я в момент, где для левого и правого блока нужно задать разный backround

Как я организовал (наворотил) на данный момент

```css
.home-collection {
  .home-collection-section {
    display: flex;
    .home-collection-left {
      position: relative;
      .home-collection-txt {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        z-index: 5;
        p.collection-man-title {
          font-family: Montserrat;
          font-style: normal;
          font-size: 24px;
          line-height: 29px;
          letter-spacing: 0.03em;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          padding-bottom: 20px;
          span.man-collection {
            font-weight: 500;
          }
        }
        p.collection-man-subtitle {
          font-family: Montserrat;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 300;
          font-size: 16px;
          line-height: 20px;

        }
      }
      .home-collection-btn {
        max-width: 80px;
        a.collection-button {
          padding: 10px 30px;
          background-color: $light-cream;
        }
      }
      .home-collection-img {
        img.home-collection-man {
          position: absolute;
          top: 10px;
          right: 15px;
          z-index: 2;
        }
      }
    }
    .home-collection-right {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      .home-collection-txt {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        z-index: 2;
        p.collection-man-title {
          font-family: Montserrat;
          font-style: normal;
          font-size: 24px;
          line-height: 29px;
          letter-spacing: 0.03em;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          padding-bottom: 20px;
          span.man-collection {
            font-weight: 500;
          }
        }
        p.collection-man-subtitle {
          font-family: Montserrat;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 300;
          font-size: 16px;
          line-height: 20px;

        }
      }
      .home-collection-btn {
        max-width: 80px;
        a.collection-button {
          padding: 10px 30px;
          background-color: $light-cream;
        }
      }
      .home-collection-img {
        img.home-collection-man {
          position: absolute;
          top: 10px;
          right: 15px;
          z-index: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
.col {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
}
.wrap {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section class="home-collection">
        <div class="home-collection-section wrap">
            <div class="home-collection-left col">
                <div class="home-collection-txt">
                    <p class="collection-man-title">
                        <span class="man-collection">
                            мужская
                        </span>
                        коллекция
                    </p>
                    <p class="collection-man-subtitle">
                        Обувь, полуверы, костюмы
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="home-collection-btn">
                    <a href="#" class="collection-button">
                        <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="" class="arrow-btn">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="home-collection-img">
                    <img src="img/collection-man.png" alt="" class="home-collection-man">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="home-collection-right col">
                <div class="home-collection-txt">
                    <p class="collection-man-title">
                        <span class="man-collection">
                            Женская
                        </span>
                        коллекция
                    </p>
                    <p class="collection-man-subtitle">
                        Обувь, полуверы, костюмы
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="home-collection-btn">
                    <a href="#" class="collection-button">
                        <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="" class="arrow-btn">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="home-collection-img">
                    <img src="img/collection-woman.png" alt="" class="home-collection-man">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.left,
.right{
  width: 50vw;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.left{
  background-color: #F9F6F1;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
.right{
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
span{
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}
button,
i{
  background-color: #D7B399;
  color: #fff;
}
button{
  padding: 5px 40px;
  border: none;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/421d417066.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left2">
      мужская коллекция
         <span>обувь, полуверы, костюмы</span>
         <button><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="rigt2">
      женская коллекция
       <span>обувь, полуверы, костюмы</span>
       <button><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что мне нужно. Попробую объяснить. 
Есть секция (home-collection), в этой секции есть 2 блока, левый ( home-collection-left col ) и правый ( home-collection-right col ) в этих двух блоках контент размещен в контейнере ( wrap ) поэтому эти 2 блока (home-collection-left col, home-collection-right col) я обернул в еще один div (home-collection-section ) и навесил класс wrap, чтобы контент не выходил за пределы контейнера (1150px). Этим div'ам (home-collection-left col, home-collection-right col) я не могу задать background, т.к. они находятся в контейнере

Comment: У меня была идея. 
Для <section class="home-collection"> разделить на 2 колонки (home-collection-left col, home-collection-right col) и внутри для каждой из них написать wrapp'ер (хз, разделить как-то контейнер напополам и позиционировать его) который будет не позволять контенту выходить за пределы контейнера, а background-color разный уже задавать для home-collection-left col, home-collection-right col

Answer (score 0):

1) Поробуй задать задний фон градиентом, с границей по центру. (если всегда граница будет проходить ровно по центру)

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(85,255,0,1) 0%, rgba(85,255,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,255,221,1) 50%, rgba(0,255,221,1) 100%);
```

Что то типа такого, только цвета под свой вариант подбери.

2) Второй вариант - это разбить всю секцию на две части как ты и сделал и каждой задать свой бэкгрануд. Более длинный вариант, но наверное более правильный.

```
<section class="section-wrapper">
<div class="left-col flex-col">
    <div class="flex-side left-side">Bar</div>
</div>
<div class="right-col flex-col">
    <div class="flex-side right-side">Foo</div>
</div>
```

```
.section-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.section-wrapper .flex-col {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
.section-wrapper .flex-col.left-col {
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
.section-wrapper .flex-col.right-col {
 justify-content: flex-start;
}
.section-wrapper .flex-col .flex-side {
 max-width: calc(1140px / 2); /* 1140 - container width */
 width: 100%;
}
.section-wrapper .flex-col .flex-side.left-side {background: red;}
.section-wrapper .flex-col .flex-side.right-side {background: yellow;}
```

Не уверен что хотя бы один однозначно правильный, но сколько людей столько и мнений. Это мой вариант =)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую оба варианта

Answer (score -1):

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block_wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block_wrap">
      <div class="block block_left">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</div>

      <div class="block block_right">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some textSome text Some text Some text Some text Some textSome text Some text Some text Some text Some textSome text Some text Some text Some text Some textSome text Some text Some text Some text Some textSome
        text Some text Some text Some text Some textSome text Some text Some text Some text Some textSome text Some text Some text Some text Some text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```